# Using google javascript library to authorize as service account for user

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-cloud-storage

I have a web-app that sends data to our Google Cloud Storage via an API. However this seems to cause problems for the users for some reason, so someone suggested me to send the data directly to the storage instead of having to go through an API.

For this I'm using the Javascript Client Library Google provides.
I've managed to implement it far enough for it to send the data correctly as an XHR-Request, but only if I'm logged in as the account that owns the project. And that doesn't really work out for the app, since many users will be logged into their own accounts so what I need is for the users to have access to my Google Cloud Storage with their own accounts.

I've done a lot of research (on here as well) to find out that I can probably accomplish this by somehow letting the service account impersonate the user's account but I don't quite know where to begin or how to accomplish that.

But the only thing I need for the whole XHR-Request to work is to get an access token I can put in the request-header. I have also already created a dedicated service account but I just don't know how to use it with the Javascript Client Library so it connects the web-app with the Google API so I get that access-token.

So how can I achieve this? And is trying to avoid making API-calls in that case even the right thing to do?

Comment: Absolutely do not do this! If it is at all possible for a user to impersonate you, they can do all kinds of things, including deleting and adding new data that is incompatible with your data structures, etc. You can only give your credentials to your (trusted) code on your (trusted) server.

Comment: I see...So is there an alternative? What should I do in that case?

Comment: You need to have your own API to add/remove items from your server. What is the problem with your current API? It doesn't make sense that some users would have problems unless they are somewhere like China and your server is in America.

Comment: The API is flakey in many ways and since it wasn't me who created it and since it's a huge one, I was looking for a quick fix first until I figure out what's wrong with the current API...
And it really doesn't make sense as to why it shouldn't work, it just sometimes doesn't although the code looks fine to me.

That's why I was hoping to put the code for saving somewhere else than the serve, to perhaps take off the pressure of the API.